# Rails 5: How to overwrite route parameters for extra member route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, ruby-on-rails-5

In Rails 5 I've figured out how to

1. [Overwrite the route parameter from `id` to something like `name`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#overriding-named-route-parameters)
2. [Add another route for a resource](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions)

So that my routes.rb looks something like this

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  resources :cats, param: :name

  resources :cats do
    get :preview, on: :member
  end

end
```

I've noticed however that my additional `preview` route does not keep the overwritten named route parameter. Instead, when looking at the output from rake routes, I have something that looks like this.

`GET    /cats/:id/preview(.:format)`

when what I was expecting, and trying to achieve, was a route that looks like

`GET    /cats/:name/preview(.:format)`

How do I *both* add an additional route to a resource while overwriting the parameter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're duplicating your routes entries for `cats`, and you've provided the block for declaring the `preview` route on the entry missing the param name override. You need to provide the override and the block in the same route declaration.

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  resources :cats, param: :name do
    get :preview, on: :member
  end
end
```

This gives you the route you want:

```
$ rake routes
           Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                      Controller#Action
      preview_cat GET    /cats/:name/preview(.:format)    cats#preview
```